# Passing Array Values in Radio Button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function to prettify radio buttons that works great except under one circumstance, when the name attribute of the button contains a bracketed array value.

This is for a shopping cart system that has selectable options via radio button, so the buttons look like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="option[218]" value="5">
<input type="radio" name="option[218]" value="6">
<input type="radio" name="option[218]" value="7">
...
```

The section of the jQuery script that's throwing the error looks like so:

```
$('input:radio[name=' + radio.attr('name') + ']')
  .not(':disabled')
  ...
```

**Error:**

*Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:radio[name=option[218]]*

Obviously it's not expecting to find brackets `[ ]` in the name value.

How can I switch this up to allow those to be found and not error out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the value inside double quotes `" "`

```
$('input:radio[name="' + radio.attr('name') + '"]')
// ---------------- ^      here and here       ^
```

So your value will be escaped properly and output as:

```
input:radio[name="option[218]"]
```

Comment: Sometimes I feel like I should just take out my brain and play with it. Thanks Felix.

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose the value in `""` to escape the special characters

```
$('input:radio[name="' + radio.attr('name') + '"]')
```

Comment: Thanks Arun. Felix beat you to the punch. Appreciate your answer though.